# How to better display metadata about a card?

Tags: layout, buttons, responsive-design, data

A Card has the following metadata:

Information: Status (ready or not), Stage (one of nine)
Actions: Edit, View Statistics, Edit, Delete, Archive

I need to display both sides of the card on this page, as well as the metadata/actions.  I can hide the Delete/Archive actions behind the Edit button if required/appropriate.

EDIT replaces both sides with editable text areas.  STATS replaces both sides with a single side containing graphs/stats.

This is what I've come up with so far (in paint):

[image]

It feels a little clunky though.  I think I'd like to keep the three-block layout, but the info in the leftmost block doesn't seem very visually appealing.  What do you think?  How would you improve it?  EDIT: This will be on a page that lists cards.

Comment: What is the purpose of having side 1 and side 2 if both sides need to be displayed on this page? How are these cards displayed on other pages? Are the cards listed in the context of a board (similar to a Kanban board)? or, are they just listed like a product backlog/queue? What goest in the text area of side 1 versus side 2?

Answer (score 2):

Additional information regarding the actual usage scenario will definitely help, but let's use what we have. I would suggest to do the following:

- fix layout a bit, in order to enhance space usage and avoid any potential chance to get a horizontal scrollbar
- visualize stages and current editing state in order to provide editing progress
- let cards to be a primary element on the form
- make form look like a form

[image]

**Update**

There is a way to simplify it even more. Simpler progress visualization can be used, like, for example, RallyDev does:

[image]

So vertical column can be replaced with simple horizontal component:

[image]

Everything depends on specific of your application. Usually it is better to have all states explicitly defined.

Comment: Nice one, I really like it, esp. the 1st approach!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

1. Remove block with metadata and leave two blocks with card sides.
2. Put metadata above cards in one line: The card is READY in STAGE ONE.
3. Put all 4 buttons below cards in one line.

So, you have three well defined areas - status information at the top, working area in the middle and command area (buttons) at the bottom of your screen.